# Persisting an Entity after encountering Exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

If an Exception is thrown while persisting an entity X, in the catch block can a call be made to a different method to persist some entity Y?

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
private X addNewX(X transientX) {
    X x = null;
    try {
        x = xDao.makePersistent(transientX); // A DB constraint will be violated and Hibernate throws PersistenceException
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        createErrorRecord(transientX, e.getMessage());
    }
    return x;
}
```

Save extra information about the error:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
private void createErrorRecord(X x, String errMsg) {
    try {
        ImportError error = new ImportError(x.getBlah(), x.moreBlah(),
                errMsg);
        impErrDao.makePersistent(error);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        logger.error(re.toString());
    }
}
```

However, `ImportError` never gets persisted. I tried `noRollbackFor` for `PersistenceException` but to no avail.

Is there something that can be done here?
Thanks

Comment: Working with hibernate session after it has thrown  an exception is a big no-no. Also you should propagate the exception further if it's unexpected.

Comment: This is not a good idea to catch `RuntimeException`…

Answer (score 0):

Using AOP for logging such exceptions seems to be the right option.